# Inject list of objects in CDI (Weld)

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld

Let's say I have an interface called `SocialNetworkService`, and three implementations - `TwitterService`, `FacebookService` and `FriendFeedService`.

Now I want, whenever my managed bean (or whatever web component) receives a message, to share it in all social networks. I tried:

```
@Inject private List<SocialNetworkService> socialNetworkServices;
```

But it didn't work (deployment error). (Also tried to the `@Any` qualifier - same result)

So, is there a way to inject a list of all (or some) implementations of an interface?

I know the rule that a given injection point should not have more than one possible bean. I guess I can achieve that by making a producer that produces the list, and using `Instance<SocialNetworkService>`, but that seems like too much for this task.

Comment: 330 and 299 .. That should be sufficient

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Combining my attempts with an answer from the Weld forum:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<SocialNetworkService> services;
```

`Instance` implements `Iterable`, so it is then possible to simply use the for-each loop. The `@Any` qualifier is needed.

---

Another way to do this is by using the event system:

- create a `MessageEvent` (containing all the information about the message)
- instead of injecting a list of social networks, simply inject the event:

  ```
  @Inject private Event<MessageEvent> msgEvent;
  ```

  and fire it: `msgEvent.fire(new MessageEvent(message));`
- observe the event in all services (regardless of their interface, which might be a plus):

  ```
  public void consumeMessageEvent(@Observes MessageEvent msgEvent) {..}
  ```

Comment: @Bozho The find-all-instances approach looks like an anti-pattern with a well-known-but-not-obvious solution using Events

Comment: well, I think both are valid. The first means more coupling, indeed, but is, for example, easier to trace later. It depends on your objectives.

Comment: (Ancient subject, I know, but also be aware of https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-535: the ordering of `@Inject @Any Instance<Something> stuff;` is not guaranteed.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the JSR-299 specification and it doesn't seem that you can do what you want to do easily and I do not have experience enough with Weld to provide code for this special case.

However, based on chapter 12.3 "Bean Discovery" you might be able to declare the implementations as @Alternative's (to avoid Weld complain about multiple implementations) and listen to ProcessBean events to collect when implementations of SocialNetworkService are seen.

Comment: that would be even more tedious than the my initial suggestion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The initial suggestion still needs to know about all your implementations - Weld cannot as far as I can see tell you.