# Inject several of the Same CDI bean into a class?

Tags: java, cdi, javabeans, java-ee-8

Currently, I have everything working with one injection of my CDI bean, but I need about 6 to 10 separate instances(?) depending on my inputs. (Ideally, I would like to be able to inject a dynamic number of the same CDI beans depending on how many I need.)

Unfortunately, I need to have the beans injected since the class depends on another CDI bean. (See the 2.CDI bean class below)

1. Clients class

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Clients {
   Publisher pub;
   Subscriber sub;
   @Inject
   ListenerBean listener;

   public void init(){
      pub = new Publisher();
      sub = new Subscriber(listener);
   }
}
```

2. CDI bean class

```java
@Dependent
public class ListenerBean{
   @Inject
   private eventHandler h;

   public void onMessage(Msg msg){
      h.doesSomething();
   }
}
```

The functionality I'm looking for, but not sure what's available out there. I haven't found anyone looking to accomplish the same thing.

```java
for(Subscriber s: listOfSubscribers){
   @Inject
   ListenerBean l;
   s = new Subscriber(l);
}

// The only thing I can do right now is
@Inject
ListenerBean listener1;
@Inject
ListenerBean listener2;
@Inject
ListenerBean listener3;
@Inject
ListenerBean listener4;
```

---

Edit: The listeners *do* need to be identifiable. (Calls a setter after injection.) Probably not the best practice but not sure how else to implement this-

- The listeners will listen to different topics (declared by the respective consumer)
- Each listener must handle their messages based off of the topic

```java
@Inject
ListenerBean listener1;
listener1.setTopic("TopicA");
```

Comment: Can't you inject `List<ListenerBean>`?

Comment: I believe that, if `ListenerBean` is `@Dependent` and you inject an `Instance<ListenerBean> listenerInstance`, then every time you do `listenerInstance.get()` you get a fresh copy. Make sure to dispose of the instances you get, once you are done with them.

Comment: This sounds like a classic example to use the standard `Event` and `@Observes` instead.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- That's not a thing... see [post 4009388](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009388/inject-list-of-objects-in-cdi-weld)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thank you! I will try this

Comment: @mtj Would this work the same way as Instance? Like `Event<Bean> e` and `e.fire(Bean)` is respective to `Instance<Bean> i` and `i.get()` ? I'm trying to understand from [docs here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.4.0.CR1/en-US/html/events.html)

Comment: @dko See the answer for an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to inject several *different* instances of a `@Dependent` scoped bean, you could do it via [programmatic lookup](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#programmatic_lookup) - in other words via `Instance<T>`.

Every bean resolution for a `@Dependent` bean via `Instance` will result in a new bean instance created. Following code illustrates that:

```
@Inject Instance<ListenerBean> instance;

public void createMultipleBeanInstances() {
  // bean1 and bean2 are two different instances because the bean is @Dependent
  // you can OFC do this in a cycle and generate as many as you like
  ListenerBean bean1 = instance.get(); 
  ListenerBean bean2 = instance.get();
}
```

Just note that dependent beans you create via programmatic lookup have their lifecycle bound to the `Instance` object meaning they will exist so long as does the `Instance`. Given that you `@Inject Instance` into the bean, it will be destroyed along with the bean it was injected into.

Comment: thank you so much, and for the example too!! Yes, I want the *different* instances injected as you described, I will see if this works for me

Comment: this is partially working for me. But if I want the ListenerBean to inject separately-- The class should be `@Dependent` scoped, right? I edited my original post to include a detail that I missed. -- I need to set a value in the ListenerBeans. But I'm not sure if `@Dependent` is the correct scope for the Listener

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue. They are identifiable and you can still do `bean1.setTopic("someTopic")`. As for scope, only you can know which scope fits your scenario. However, if by `Listener`  you mean a CDI observer, than note that `@Dependent` scope will mean a *separate* bean instance will be created to observe fired events and will be destroyed afterwards.

Comment: Actually, it was a separate issue. This solution, worked!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: what if we need both instance of application scope or session scope. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation following my comment. I might be misunderstanding your question though.

First of all, your code looks basically like the implementation of a multicaster: you inject several objects which all implement a common interface to call the same method.

I think, that in trying to inject the various receiver objects, you basically have an X-Y-problem: does the emitter really need to *know* the receivers, or is it enough, that the event reaches the targets?

If I am right with the assumption, that your emitter does not really need to *know* the subscribers, you can simply use the `Event` standard mechanism:

First, define a message (which can carry additional information, but this is not specifically necessary, you just need a class):

```
public class MyMessage {
     // if needed, add some fields
}
```

Then, in your emitter, inject the corresponding event type, and use it to fire the message:

```
@Inject
private Event<MyMessage> myEvent;  // note: type is message, not the bean

...

myEvent.fire(new MyMessage()); // to broadcast the message to everyone who is interested
```

In your subscribers, just @Observe the message:

```
public void theMethodWeWantCalled(@Observes MyMessage messageObject) {
    // do things here
}
```

That's it: no need to couple emitter and subscriber.

Comment: thanks, this makes more sense. Unfortunately, I think the emitter does need to know the receivers? Since I still need them to have a field set :( See the edit I just made on my post.